# Elasticsearch date math, are years truncating incorrectly?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to do date math, to get "any date in the previous year". This seems like it should be simple:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "modifiedDate": {
        "gte": "now-1y/y",
        "lte": "now/y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I check, with validate, I get from 1/1 last year, to Dec 31st *this year*. This is a two year span, while I want a one year span.

```
indexname/_validate/query?rewrite=true
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "valid": true,
  "explanations": [
    {
      "index": "indexname",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": "+modifiedDate:[1640995200000 TO 1704067199999] #FieldExistsQuery [field=_primary_term]"
    }
  ]
}
```

From the examples on the date math docs, doing /y should *truncate* rather than round. And either way it should do the same last year, and this year. It's September 19th, in both years, so it should result in the same date in both years.

So, I think my query should be from (a year ago today, truncated to Jan 1 last year) to (current date, truncated to Jan 1, this year)

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mentally rounding the expression to a particular date and then trying to make conclusions based on that day. In reality, there is another factor at work here - the rounding level. In your case we are rounding not to a particular date, but to a year. It's easier to understand on an example.

Let's consider for a moment your query

```
        "gte": "now-1y/y",
        "lte": "now/y"
```

Today, Sue 19, 2023 the lower bound `now-1y/y` is getting resolved into year 2022, the part `now/y` is resolved into year 2023. So we are selecting all dates that have a year **greater than or equal** to 2022 and **less than or equal** to 2023. That includes 2 years starting from Jan 1, 2022 all the way to Dec 31, 2023.

If you want to include just one year, then instead of using `lte` as the upper bound you should use `lt`:

```
        "gte": "now-1y/y",
        "lt": "now/y"
```

That condition will match all dates that have year all dates that have a year greater than or equal to 2022 and strictly less than 2023. Basically just year 2022, which will include all dates starting from Jan 1, 2022 until Dec 31, 2022.

Comment: I assumed that date expressions resolved to a point in time, not a range (a year is range). This seems to contradict what is documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math
You can see that it specifically says that rounding to a day produces a point in time: "2001-03-01 00:00:00". I hope you can see why I would expect a year to do the same. In fact, I think M,D,H,M,S have to work the way I expect (unless now/M matches this month in any year). They have to resolve to a point in time, so why wouldn't year?

Comment: That documentation page is partially incorrect. It only describes one mode of operation that is used in some places such as index name resolution. If you check the docs for the [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#range-query-date-math-rounding) that has a much better example that shows how date math can round down as well as up depending on where the date math expression appears. The same expression can be resolved into 4 different milliseconds when it appears in lt,gt,lte and gte. They have an examples for `/M`.